# Django Admin actions select issue

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-1.3

I am using Django 1.3 and have the following issue:

In the Admin list page, if you have enough objects to result in pagination (more than 100 if you haven't changed ModelAdmin.list_per_page) there is an issue with the actions links, and none of them seem to work.

These links are meant to show how many items you have selected, allow you to select all (through all pages) or clear selection. I am currently getting very weird behaviour and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Could please elaborate on the 'weird behavior' that you are getting.

Comment: Sorry about that. When you click on 'Select all', nothing happens. And when you click on 'Clear selection', again no items are selected, but the background on the items changes to yellow as though they had been selected.

I must add that without pagination, there is no issue since these links will not show.

Comment: sounds like messed-up css/js, you may want to check the HTML class of item which should have normal bg but been colored yellow through firebug

Comment: Using Firebug, and seeing if you are getting any js errors (which could be a reason for nothing happening).

Comment: I do use Firebug and there are no JS errors, which is what is puzzling me at the moment.

Comment: Does the same page work well with small amounts of data?

Comment: 1. Have you simply added the admin manager for the app/model or have you overrode any default methods? 2. Are you taking data directly from DB or is there anything else as intermediate? 3. Could you please provide some screenshots of the whole process, if possible? 4. Please provide some more information as its difficult to catch a mistake.

Comment: I did restyle the admin and it works fine unless there is pagination. I am going to load a vanilla copy of Django and see if the issue persists. I will also try and make some screen shots and link them up here.

1. No override on methods.
2. Data is taken directly from DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved thanks to the suggestions provided above. It was indeed a CSS issue.